# Optimising code used for inserting, updating or deleting relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model, eloquent

I'm writing logic to insert, update or delete a table row, based on the provided input and existing data.

- If there is no input, and the row exists, the row should be deleted.
- If there is input, but the row does not exist, it should be created.
- And lastly, if there is input and the row exists, the row should be updated.

This project is test code for an `attributes` table, which has a `name`, `value` and `media_id` (which references the piece of media that has been given the attributes). The `name` and `media_id` are unique together (one media cannot have two attributes with the same name). It is important to the project that the insert, update and delete are used, as opposed to leaving them blank if empty.

My question is whether there is an easier way to carry out this logic. It would have been okay to me to use it for just one input, but when there is two (`name` and `description`) and I might potentially add more later, it seems like a massive piece of code to use. Is there a more efficient way?

---

My database migration:

```
Schema::create('attributes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('media_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->text('value')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->unique(['media_id', 'name']);
    $table->foreign('media_id')->references('id')->on('media')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

---

My view:

```
<form action="{{ Request::path() }}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <label style="display:block" for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="{{ $attributes->get('name') ? $attributes->get('name')->value : '' }}">
    <label style="display:block" for="description">Description</label>
    <textarea name="description" id="description">{{ $attributes->get('description') ? $attributes->get('description')->value : '' }}</textarea>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

---

My makeshift controller:

```
Route::post('/', function(Request $request) {
    $media = Media::find(1);

    $attributes = $media->attributes->keyBy('name');

    if($request->input('name')) {
        if($attributes->get('name')) {
            $attributes->get('name')->value = $request->input('name');
            if(!$attributes->get('name')->save()) {
                return "error updating name";
            }
        } else {
            $attribute = new Attribute;
            $attribute->name = 'name';
            $attribute->value = $request->input('name');
            if(!$media->attributes()->save($attribute)) {
                return "error inserting name";
            }
        }
    } else {
        if($attributes->get('name')) {
            if(!$attributes->get('name')->delete()) {
                return "error deleting name";
            }
        }
    }
    if($request->input('description')) {
        if($attributes->get('description')) {
            $attributes->get('description')->value = $request->input('description');
            if(!$attributes->get('description')->save()) {
                return "error updating description";
            }
        } else {
            $attribute = new Attribute;
            $attribute->name = 'description';
            $attribute->value = $request->input('description');
            if(!$media->attributes()->save($attribute)) {
                return "error inserting description";
            }
        }
    } else {
        if($attributes->get('description')) {
            if(!$attributes->get('description')->delete()) {
                return "error deleting description";
            }
        }
    }
});
return redirect('/');
```

*(There is a controller for GET as well, which displays the form and the database output. I didn't bother including it as I felt it wasn't necessary.)*

---

My dead simple model:

```
class Attribute extends Model
{
    public function media()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Media');
    }
}
```

Comment: A couple of things, the `if($request->input('name'))` section should be `if($request->has('name'))`, that will always return a `true` or `false`. If it returns `false`, you can run the `delete` on the table. The you can use the `firstOrNew` method on the `attribute` table to either update or insert the `attribute` to the table by searching for the `model` and `name`.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use restful routes and built in validation?

Comment: @KevinCompton It's being used a specific way for a user interface, but I was considering actually rewriting it based on the information here, and then making the user interface run using Angular.

Comment: @Furze Ahhh I see. I recommend Vuejs, much cleaner than angular.

Comment: @Furze, I use Angular for the frontend of all my projects, and Laravel as the API framework. Especially usefully with rate limiting and the oAuth packages available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here is what I got:

Routes File:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Media;
use App\Models\Attribute;

Route::get('/', function(Request $request) {
    $media = Media::all();
    $media->attributes;
    return response()->json($media);
});
Route::get('/media/{id}', function($id, Request $request) {
    $media = Media::find($id);
    $media->attributes;
    return response()->json($media);
});
Route::post('/media/{id}', function($id, Request $request) {
    if($request->has('name')) {
        $attr = Attribute::firstOrNew(['name' => 'name', "media_id" => $id]);
        $attr->value = $request->input('name');
        $attr->save();
    } else {
        Attribute::where('name', 'name')->where("media_id",$id)->first()->delete();
    }
    if($request->has('description')) {
        $attr = Attribute::firstOrNew(['name' => 'description', "media_id" => $id]);
        $attr->value = $request->input('description');
        $attr->save();
    } else {
        Attribute::where('name', 'description')->where("media_id",$id)->first()->delete();
    }
});
return redirect('/');
```

Media Model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Media extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'media';

    protected $appends = [];

    public function attributes() {
        return $this->hasMany(Attribute::class);
    }
}
```

Attribute Model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Attribute extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'attributes';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'media_id'];

    public function media() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Media::class);
    }
}
```

Basically, by making Attributes a model, I was able to do `firstOrNew()` on the attributes table, and looking for `['name' => 'name', "media_id" => $id]` on the `firstOrNew()` makes it so it either finds the matching row, or creates a new one. You can then update the value column based on such.

Much shorter, much more simplified, and it allows your attributes to be a model!

(My opinion, almost everything should be a model :P)

EDIT: I modified it to my most recent code. Changed it from `belongsTo("Media")` to `belongsTo(Media::class)`, and removed the `dd()` from the routes file.

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask, what's the significance of the `$media->attributes;` on its own?

Comment: @Furze I'm assuming he's just trying to load the `attributes` attribute, so it'll be included in the response. You could do this by eager loading the `attributes`, though: `Media::with('attributes')->get();` in the `'/'` route and `Media::with('attributes')->find($id);` in the `'/media/{id}'` route.

Comment: I could have done the `with`, but I opted for the manual way. Just personal preference is all.